# How to sort array?

Tags: haxe

I have an array of points:

```
var pointsCutAt:Array<Point>
```

I need to sort the array based on `y` access, and my implementation is:

```
ArraySort.sort(pointsCutAt,function(a, b):Int{
                        if (a.y > b.y)
                        return 1;
                        else
                        if (a.y < b.y)
                        return -1
                        else
                        return 0;
                    });
```

However, I've noticed that the passed array is not being sorted:

Before:

```
[(x=360, y=90),(x=360, y=270),(x=360, y=180),(x=360, y=360)]
```

After:

```
[(x=360, y=90),(x=360, y=270),(x=360, y=180),(x=360, y=360)]
```

In the haxe [documentation](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/ds/ArraySort.html):

> ```
> static sort<T> (a:Array<T>, cmp:T ‑> T ‑> Int):Void
> ```
>
> This operation modifies Array a in place.

So, I am missing something?

**EDIT**

I found that the error was not related to the sort function, the var isHorizontal was simply wrong, so I was sorting with respect to x while I was expecting y:

```
        if (pointsCutAt.length > 0)
        {
            // sort them first!
            if (isHorizontal)
            {
                ArraySort.sort(pointsCutAt,function(a, b):Int{
                    if (a.x > b.x)
                    return 1;
                    else
                    if (a.x < b.x)
                    return -1
                    else
                    return 0;
                });
            }else
            {
                ArraySort.sort(pointsCutAt,function(a, b):Int{
                    if (a.y > b.y)
                    return 1;
                    else
                    if (a.y < b.y)
                    return -1
                    else
                    return 0;
                });
            }
```

I discovered that when I tried to prepare a minimal sample.. thanks any way..

The reason why I didn't use Array.sort is what is written in the docs:

> The sort operation is not guaranteed to be stable, which means that
>   the order of equal elements may not be retained. For a stable Array
>   sorting algorithm, haxe.ds.ArraySort.sort() can be used instead.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue.  Can you provide a complete (but minimal) example?  Also, take a look at [this](http://try.haxe.org/#D008d) demo...

Comment: Did you try Array.sort instead?

Comment: @larsiusprime kindly see my note above about Array.sort

Comment: Should note that on some platforms Array.sort should be considerably faster than ArraySort.sort. Sort stability is actually quite a rare requirement from my experience, and your case sort of suggests it isn't required.